# Store news from mysql in php array!

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have following script:

```
$cbid = 0;
    $arrayid = 0;
    while ($FINDNEWSresult = mysql_fetch_array($FINDNEWSquery)) {
        echo "<tr>";
        // Prvi stolpec - označevanje (checkbox)
        echo "<td class=\"middlerow checkbox\"><input id=\"" . $FINDNEWSresult['NEWSid'] . "\" type=\"checkbox\" /></td>";
        echo "<td class=\"middlerow\"><a class=\"ahover\" href=\"?mod=news&command=edit&edit=true&id=" . $FINDNEWSresult['NEWSid'] ."\">" . substr($FINDNEWSresult['NEWStitle'], 0, $MOD_NEWStextlimit)  . "</a></td>";
        echo "<td class=\"middlerow\"><a class=\"ahover\" href=\"?mod=news&command=edit&edit=true&id=" . $FINDNEWSresult['NEWSid'] ."\">" . substr($FINDNEWSresult['NEWStext'], 0, $MOD_NEWStextlimit) . "</a></td>";
        echo "<td class=\"middlerow\">" . $FINDNEWSresult['NEWSuser'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td class=\"middlerow\">" . $FINDNEWSresult['NEWSdate'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        $NEWSarray = array ( $arrayid => array ( "Id" => $FINDNEWSresult['NEWSid'],
                                                 "Title" => $FINDNEWSresult['NEWStitle'],
                                                 "Text" => $FINDNEWSresult['NEWStext'],
                                                 "User" => $FINDNEWSresult['NEWSuser'],
                                                 "Date" => $FINDNEWSresult['NEWSdate']
                                                )
                            );
        // Povecaj $cb zarad checkbox id
        $cbid++;
        $arrayid++;
    }
```

How to modify script, that array will be filled with each news?
Currently, array stores only last news.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
$cbid = 0;
        $arrayid = 0;
        $NEWSarray = array(); // Not necessary but good for clarity
        while ($FINDNEWSresult = mysql_fetch_array($FINDNEWSquery)) {
                echo "<tr>";
                // Prvi stolpec - oznacevanje (checkbox)
                echo "<td class=\"middlerow checkbox\"><input id=\"" . $FINDNEWSresult['NEWSid'] . "\" type=\"checkbox\" /></td>";
                echo "<td class=\"middlerow\"><a class=\"ahover\" href=\"?mod=news&command=edit&edit=true&id=" . $FINDNEWSresult['NEWSid'] ."\">" . substr($FINDNEWSresult['NEWStitle'], 0, $MOD_NEWStextlimit)  . "</a></td>";
                echo "<td class=\"middlerow\"><a class=\"ahover\" href=\"?mod=news&command=edit&edit=true&id=" . $FINDNEWSresult['NEWSid'] ."\">" . substr($FINDNEWSresult['NEWStext'], 0, $MOD_NEWStextlimit) . "</a></td>";
                echo "<td class=\"middlerow\">" . $FINDNEWSresult['NEWSuser'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td class=\"middlerow\">" . $FINDNEWSresult['NEWSdate'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                $NEWSarray[] = array ( $arrayid => array ( "Id" => $FINDNEWSresult['NEWSid'],
                                                                                                 "Title" => $FINDNEWSresult['NEWStitle'],
                                                                                                 "Text" => $FINDNEWSresult['NEWStext'],
                                                                                                 "User" => $FINDNEWSresult['NEWSuser'],
                                                                                                 "Date" => $FINDNEWSresult['NEWSdate']
                                                                                                )
                                                        );
                // Povecaj $cb zarad checkbox id
                $cbid++;
                $arrayid++;
        }
```

Alternatively to the [] you can use [PHPs array_push](http://de3.php.net/array_push) as well.

Answer (score 1):

You need to append to the array, not to create it all over again.

```
$NEWSarray[] = <new_element> ;
```

or

```
array_push($NEWSarray, <new_element>);
```